# Is java.lang.reflect.Method thread safe?

Tags: java

Is `java.lang.reflect.Method` thread safe?

Profiling result of my program showed that `Class.getMethod()` took considerable computing time when called many times, a little more than I expected.
I can call this once and store the resulting method somewhere easily accessible. 
But then, multiple web worker threads will use the stored `Method` object concurrently.

Is this safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Method is safe to use accross multiple threads provided you don't change the Method's state after making it available to multiple threads.e.g. You can call setAccessible(true) and setAccessible(false) in two threads and the result would be not thread safe.  However this has no really good use.

In short, Method.setAccessible() is not techincally thread safe, but you should be able to use it in a thread safe way.

Comment: By the way, isn't `setAccessible` a security leak? If some code has the right to set something accessible, later another code can come and use the private method without more security checks.

Comment: Unless your SecurityManager prevents it, you can access protected, package local and private methods. It improves the the access performance of even public methods by overriding the checks.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about a case with Security manager installed ... and different privileges for different parts of code. But I'll better open another question about this than using the comments to an unrelated question for this.

Comment: Ah, just made some experiments: In fact each Method (or Field/Constructor) object has its own accessible state, and on each call to `getMethod()` etc. you get a new one. So as long as you don't share this object with the untrusted code (or give this untrusted code a new non-accessible copy), you are good.

Answer (score 5):

Java classes are guaranteed to be defined only once per ClassLoader instance, so you can safely assume that the definition, including methods and their signatures will not change through time, so you can safely "cache" them for use by multiple threads.

However, keep in mind that classes with the same fully qualified name (package + class name) can be defined differently by separate ClassLoader instances.

Answer (score 0):

The class definition isn't going to change, so unless you are loading different classes in different threads (from separate libraries, say), the Method object should be thread safe. (Of course, whether the method itself being called by reflection is thread-safe is a different question.)