# Java Reflection and thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I've got some methods that reflect a class, e.g.:

```
type.getMethods()
method.getAnnotation(annotationClass)
method.getParameterTypes()
method.getParameterAnnotations()[paramIndex];
method.getParameterTypes()[paramIndex];
```

The application is multi-threaded. Is it safe to call these methods without locking in place?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349383/is-java-lang-reflect-method-thread-safe

Comment: It should say in the Java spec. If it doesn't mention thread-safety, assume they're not.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there is any danger of getting different results from different threads that call any of those methods at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

It is safe because you don't change anything.

Comment: If we know that `foo.get(...)` doesn't change anything, that does not guarantee that any thread t can safely call `foo.get(...)` at any time.  What happens if some other thread u calls `foo.set(...)`?  That could be "safe" or it could be "unsafe" depending on how the Foo class is implemented.

Comment: OP says about calling reflection API methods. Not methods on the objects themselves. So it's perfectly thread safe to know that some class has some methods.

Comment: OK, so the reason why those method calls are safe is not because those methods don't change anything, but because _nothing_ changes the values that they return.